# Graphical representation of an equation

Tags: graphing-functions

How to plot a graph of the equation 
$12x^2-36x +15+ 16y^2 = 0$
I don't know how to plot that. Can you please give me the graph of this equation?

Comment: I think [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12x%5E2-36x+%2B15%2B+16y%5E2+%3D+0) is what you are looking for. Wolfram Alpha is a very useful site for getting this sort of information.

Comment: It should not go through origin. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry, that graph probably wasn't zoomed in enough. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12x%5E2-36x+%2B15%2B+16y%5E2+%3D+0,+x%3D0) will show that it doesn't actually ever reach $x=0$, so it can't touch the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an elipse generally of the form $$\frac{(X-X_0)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(Y-Y_0)^2}{b^2}=1$$ where $(X_0,Y_0)$ is the center of the ellipse, and a and b are the semi-axes.  Somehow you have to get your problem into this form.  But immediately you see that there is no Y term, so you know that $Y_0 = 0$.

Knowing that the widest diameter of the ellipse is on the X axis, you can solve as Leibovici above did.

To find the left and right boundaries of the ellipse, set Y=0 and factor $12X^2-36X+15$ to get $3(2x-5)(2x-1)$.  The center of the ellipse is half way between these two roots of $\frac{5}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ at $X_0 = \frac{3}{2}$.

To find the top and bottom boundaries of the ellipse, set $X = \frac{3}{2}$ and solve for Y.

The bottleneck in the problem was the factoring job.  Once that was done, the rest was easy!

Answer (score 1):

Observe we have
\begin{align}
12x^2-36x+15+16y^2=&\ 12(x^2-3x+\frac{9}{4})-27+15+16y^2\\
=&\ 12\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+16y^2-14=0
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2}{14/12}+\frac{y^2}{14/16} = 1
\end{align}
i.e. you have an ellipse centered at $(3/2, 0)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the problem explicit solving for $y$ equation $$12x^2-36x +15+ 16y^2 = 0$$ This will give $$y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}  \sqrt{-4 x^2+12 x-5}$$ Since $-4 x^2+12 x-5 \geq 0\implies \frac 12 \leq x \leq \frac 52$.

Plot the two branches and get the ellipse identified by Jacky Chong.